# www.dlinkddns.com redirected to 127.0.0.1 instead of 52.21.177.216

Tags: dns, ip, ip-address

I've been creating a Website, and for all intents and purposes, it is working fine.

However, the problem here is that I cannot properly access www.dlinkddns.com on my PC , which is the dynamic DNS service I use for my Website. Instead, it brought me to the webpage that I had locally stored. I will want to access it to check if there's anything wrong, but my PC isn't letting me.

On the flip side, I can successfully visit the dlink site when I use my Samsung Galaxy S4 and the problem is nonexistent.

### PROBLEM STATEMENT:

*When at my router config page ( model: DIR-615 ), I clicked at a link that would normally bring me to www.dlinkddns.com. Instead, it brought me to the webpage that I had locally stored.

## Here are the points of interest that I may have so far uncovered:

1. I have used 2 devices while trying to solve this problem. 1 Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.2, and the other, a custom built PC running Windows 7 64-bit.
2. Both devices are using connected to the same router, the Samsung Galaxy S4 by Wi-Fi and the custom built PC by physical ethernet connection.
3. Thinking that it may be a problem related to the hosts file, I created a backup of the entries, and then deleted everything in the hosts file. The problem wasn't solved when I restarted my PC.
4. While pinging the dlink site from my Samsung Galaxy S4, the returned IP address was : 52.21.177.216
5. While pinging the dlink site from my custom built PC, the returned IP address was : 127.0.0.1
6. I typed 52.21.177.216 in the browser of my custom built PC, and although it was able to connect to the dlink site successfully, Google Chrome says that : "The identity of the website has not been verified". I don't think it's wise to continue using this method of connecting to the dlink site.

## It is at this point that I ask for help. Here is the lead that I think is correct:

Something is redirecting my custom built PC to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of 52.21.177.216 when I try to connect to the dlink site.

Or it's a problem with the router, but I doubt that, because my S4 was able to connect to the dlink site using the same network, albeit by wireless connection.

Or it's my ISP doing something to redirect my PC. However, I see no reason for my ISP to redirect me away from a Dynamic DNS website.

I have tried searching Google but the search results are always irrelevant when “dlinkddns” is included in my search query.

### EDIT:

"3. Thinking that it may be a problem related to the hosts file, I created a backup of the entries, and then deleted everything in the hosts file. The problem wasn't solved when I restarted my PC."

Please read the descriptions properly before replying/commenting to a question. I have taken time to include the details, as I expect those that do reply, expect a proper explanation from me.

I have checked the hosts file, and deleted everything in it. When I restarted my PC, the dlink site still could not work. In addition to that, I booted Windows 8.1 from the same PC, and the dlink site still could not work. The hosts file in Windows 8.1 was never edited. Not only that, I discovered that when loading another site "malaysia.kinokuniya.com", the same error messages appear.

It seems that random Web sites are coming up with errors when connecting to them.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the IP of your PC. Also your que is too long to read.

Comment: What name(domain name) did you give your custom built PC.  It is possible that if the name is your custom web site name then it will resolve the name internally and direct you to your own machine via 127.0.0.1 ( the IP address of your 'localhost')

Comment: the other place to look would be your "hosts" file to see if you have that domain name pointing to 127.0.0.1 .  I do this on occasion when developing a site locally.  Have to remember to remove then domain from hosts when done.

Answer (score 0):

I think your host file is pointing to the local server. Check the host file in your pc. Erase the line linked to your domain

Answer (score 0):

Wireless routers are networking devices that are known to play a very important role in connecting networks and allowing communication to happen seamlessly between various devices. Along with many other brands, D-Link has also enrolled many router models to help one enhance the speed of the existing network. However, the user can only enjoy this if he performs the [Dlink router setup](https://192-168-10-1.cc/dlink-router-setup-via-user-interface-quick-installation-guide/) process.